# Unable To Bind Parameter?

Tags: if-statement, verilog

I am trying to create multiple adders via Verilog to compare the speed of each adder.

I am getting the following error `Unable to bind parameter WIDTH in arith_unit`

This is my code so far:

```
module arith_unit 
#(
parameter ADDER_TYPE = 0,
parameter WIDTH = 8)
(input [WIDTH-1:0] a,
input [WIDTH-1:0] b,    
output [WIDTH-1:0] sum,
);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (ADDER_TYPE == 0) 
begin
    ripple_carry rc1 (a, b, cin, sum, cout);
end

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
else if (ADDER_TYPE == 1) 
begin
   carry_bypass cb1 (a, b, cin, sum, cout);
end

//// more else statment for ADDER_TYPE...

endmodule  

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module ripple_carry_4_bit(a, b, cin, sum, cout);

input [3:0] a,b;
input cin;
wire c1,c2,c3;
output [3:0] sum;
output cout;

full_adder fa0(.a(a[0]), .b(b[0]),.cin(cin), .sum(sum[0]),.cout(c1));
full_adder fa1(.a(a[1]), .b(b[1]), .cin(c1), .sum(sum[1]),.cout(c2));
full_adder fa2(.a(a[2]), .b(b[2]), .cin(c2), .sum(sum[2]),.cout(c3));
full_adder fa3(.a(a[3]), .b(b[3]), .cin(c3), .sum(sum[3]),.cout(cout));

endmodule

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module ripple_carry (a, b, cin, sum, cout);

input [WIDTH-1:0] a,b;
input cin;
wire c1,c2,c3, c4, c5, c6, c7;
output [WIDTH-1:0] sum;
output cout;

if (WIDTH == 8) begin  //<-------- compiler is pointing here as the problem
    ripple_carry_4_bit rca1 (.a(a[3:0]),.b(b[3:0]),.cin(cin), .sum(sum[3:0]),.cout(c1));
    ripple_carry_4_bit rca2 (.a(a[7:4]),.b(b[7:4]),.cin(c1), .sum(sum[7:4]),.cout(cout));
end

else if (WIDTH == 16) begin
    ripple_carry_4_bit rca1 (.a(a[3:0]),.b(b[3:0]),.cin(cin), .sum(sum[3:0]),.cout(c1));
    ripple_carry_4_bit rca2 (.a(a[7:4]),.b(b[7:4]),.cin(c1), .sum(sum[7:4]),.cout(c2));
    ripple_carry_4_bit rca3 (.a(a[11:8]),.b(b[11:8]),.cin(c2), .sum(sum[11:8]),.cout(c3));
    ripple_carry_4_bit rca4 (.a(a[15:12]),.b(b[15:12]),.cin(c3), .sum(sum[15:12]),.cout(cout));
end

//// more else statment for 32 & 64 bits...

endmodule
```

I looked online and it seems that my if and else statements are correct. So I am assuming that my `WIDTH` is declared wrong? I tried passing in `WIDTH` via `module ripple_carry (a, b, cin, sum, cout, WIDTH);` kind of how you would do it with C++, but I still get the same error.

I've tested the `ripple_carry` on its own (no if statements, no parameter) with 8 bits, 16 bits, etc. and it works fine. So I know that my logic for the `ripple_carry` is fine.

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the `if ... else if` be wrapped in a `generate` block?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Really? I checked `asic-world` and their `if and else`  example did not have a `generate` block.

Comment: On `asic-world`, they're not conditionally declaring hardware, they're using `if else` for sequential logic in an `always @` block. Completely different.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh ok I see. I've fixed the `bind parameter` with the `generate` block. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It would have helped to show the exact error message with the line number, but you are missing a WIDTH parameter declaration in the `module ripple_carry`.

```
module ripple_carry #(parameter WIDTH=8)(...
```

And add it when instantiating it inside the generate block.

```
   ripple_carry #(WIDTH) (a, b, cin, sum, cout);
```